# htaccess multiple rewrite rules multiple subfolders

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have trouble understanding the way htaccess works.

This is the folder structure (approximate sample)

```
# DocumentRoot
# |-- main
# |   |-- site
# |   |   |-- assets
# |   |   |   |-- test.js
# |   |   |-- index.php
# |   |
# |   |-- common
# |   |   |-- assets
# |   |   |   |-- test.js
# |   |
# |   |-- .htaccess
```

These are the sample redirects I'm hoping to achieve

```
# http://www.example.com/main/assets/test.js            => /main/site/assets/test.js
# http://www.example.com/main/common/assets/test.js     => /main/common/assets/test.js
# http://www.example.com/main/common/path/to/file       => /main/common/path/to/file
# http://www.example.com/main                           => /main/site/index.php
# http://www.example.com/main/part/url                  => /main/site/index.php
```

My attempt at htaccess file looks like this:

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^assets/(.*)$ site/assets/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^common/(.*)$ common/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ site/index.php [L]
```

My Problem:
Every Url gets routed to index.php. What have I understood wrong?

Currently all processing for the query and partial url is handled in php. I only need to serve resources from the two asset folders and any other urls to go to the index.php.

Sorry if this looks like I'm trying to get my fish for the day but learning to fish i.e. experimenting is getting me nowhere.

Thanks in advance for all the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
> RewriteRule ^assets/(.*)$ site/assets/$1 [L]
> RewriteRule ^common/(.*)$ common/$1 [L]
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ site/index.php [L]
> ```

`RewriteCond` directives only apply to the first `RewriteRule` that follows. So, the 2nd two `RewriteRule` directives are going to execute *unconditionally* (which is why everything is being rewritten to `site/index.php`).

I'm not sure what `RewriteRule ^common/(.*)$ common/$1 [L]` is intended to do - it looks like a potential rewrite loop.

The two *conditions* check that the request maps to a file or directory - which seems to be the opposite of what you want to do. From your folder structure `/main/assets/test.js` *does not* map to an existing file, so needs to be rewritten.

Try the following instead:

```
 # If a request maps to a file or directory (but not the root directory) then stop
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
 RewriteRule . - [L]

 # Any assets (that don't exist) are rewritten to the /site/assets/ subdir
 RewriteRule ^(assets/.*) site/$1 [L]

 # Everything else is rewritten to the site/index.php file
 RewriteRule ^ site/index.php [L]
```

> These are the sample **redirects** I'm hoping to achieve

Note that these are more commonly referred to as *internal* "rewrites", not strictly "redirects". "Redirects" implies *external redirects* (ie. 3xx response). Although the Apache docs are a little ambiguous in this regard, they do quantify them as "*internal* redirects" when stated.

Comment: Thankyou, this solution works for me now. I agree The 'common' line is misleading.  To provide an explanation: It contains the framework that has fixed php and assets. when we want to change the site I only drop in the new site folder and rename (later delete) the old site. The design of htaccess is to restrict access only to site and common (the other folders including the old site are not accessible).

Comment: To add to the above comment: sometimes I use `RewriteRule ^sys/(.*)$ common/$1 [L]` i.e. a different word in the url (not exact folder name).